# MDI Child Not Showing After Being Closed Once

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Hi every programmer here:
I am a rookie in programming
I have two forms

1. Main_ form witch is an mdicontainer.
2. Registration form is an mdichild in Main_form

I made this code to open the registration form only one at the same time.
the problem is that when I close the registration form and click the `NewRegToolStripMenuItem_Click` to open it again it's not working. How can fix it so that every time I close the form and then click the button it opens again?
Thanks a lot.

```
Customer_Regisration_Form cf;


private void NewRegToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cf == null | IsDisposed)
        { cf = new Customer_Regisration_Form();
            cf.MdiParent = this;
            cf.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're checking IsDisposed. That is the property on the MDI form, not your registration form. You probably want cf.IsDisposed. However, this question would be more complete if you showed what you do when you close the registration form.

Comment: First thanks for your answer

I close the registration form from the [x] on the top.

and then press the button in the menu strip but the form is not shown again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one instance open at a time, perhaps should you consider the use of [**Form.ShowDialog**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx). This shall show your `RegistrationForm` as a modal dialog.

```
var registrationForm = new RegistrationForm();
registrationForm.ShowDialog();
```

This shall oblige the user to quit this dialog before he/she can do anything else. If you want to refer to the same open instance of your `RegistrationForm` without making it a formal dialog, than use the [**Form.MdiChildren**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren(v=vs.110).aspx) property on your `MainForm` and see whether it contains an instance of the target form.

```
var registrationForm = mainForm.MdiChildren.OfType<RegistrationForm>().SingleOrDefault();
if (registrationForm == null) {
    registrationForm = new RegistrationForm();
    registrationForm.MdiParent = this;
    registrationForm.Show();
} else if (registrationForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) 
    registrationForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
else
    registrationForm.Activate();
```

The above shall veirfy whether there's already opened `RegistrationForm` among the `MainForm`'s children, and stick with it if it can be found. Then it restores its normal state if it has been previously minimized and the application gives it the focus calling the [**Form.Activate**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Otherwise, it simply creates a new instance and shows it.

Comment: THANKS ALOT  Will Marcouiller..

THATS WORK FINE. BIG Regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a couple problems:

1. You are checking `IsDisposed`, which is a property of the MDI and isn't relevant to this if statement.
2. You are only showing the registration form if it is null or disposed.

Try updating your code as below and see if that helps:

```
Customer_Regisration_Form cf;

private void NewRegToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cf == null || cr.IsDisposed)
    { cf = new Customer_Regisration_Form();
        cf.MdiParent = this;
    }

    cf.Show();
}
```

Note that I changed your `|` to a `||`, this is a [short circuiting logical or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) which will not continue to evaluate other conditions in the statement once one has failed. This will prevent a null reference exception on the second condition of the if statement. I basically never use `|` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the form as a global variable.

```
private frmForm frm = new frmForm();
```

Then

```
private void btnSomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frm.Visible == true)
    {
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Show();
        return;
    }

    if (frm.IsDisposed)
    {
        frm = new frmForm ();
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Show();
        return;
    }

    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.Show();
}
```